# Qtcreator error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c, qt-creator, dbus, gdbus

My specific error is when trying to run a GDBus example code from here: https://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.30/GDBusConnection.html

The error looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: undefined reference to symbol 'g_variant_type_checked_'

//usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [GDbus_test] Error 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the library to the .pro file via `LIBS += ....`

After trying unsuccessfully variants of "libglib-2.0", I learned that the way to get the library name from the error is to replace the "lib" with a "-l", so -lglib-2.0.

The error was solved after adding

`LIBS += -lglib-2.0` as well as

```
\  -lgio-2.0 \
    -lgobject-2.0 \
```

when those missing DSO errors then popped up (libgio-2.0 and libgobject-2.0)